# Generating ee.Image from ee.Dictionary?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to make an ee.Image from an ee.Dictionary of values.

I generated a dictionary using the following piece of code that takes a sample pixel's data from an image collection and generates a dictionary of values where each value of the pixel in the image collection(monthlyNDVI) is now an entry in the dictionary (created a time-series for a given pixel).

```
var reference_signal_list = monthlyNDVI.iterate(referenceTimeSeries, 
ee.List([]));
print('Reference Signal', reference_signal_list);

var referenceTimeSeries = function(current, previous) {
var temp = current.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), reference_point, 30);
return ee.List(previous).add(ee.Number(temp));
};
```

I now want to create an image from this dictionary in a way that each entry in the dictionary becomes a band in the resultant image.

Comment: Does this work? [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/591d4bfbcf4a513ac55ea43d00b61f9f)? Otherwise, please post a link of your code, now your monthlyNDVI timeseries (?) is not reproducable.

Comment: @Kuik this does not work. It says ImageError: Dictionary: Element at position 0 is not a string. Here's the link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b3eede9008dbd9aab6b9a7a32a03cbdb

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this goal easier (and faster) by mapping over the image collection. That does the job simultanouesly, instead of on after each other using iterate.

While mapping over the image collection, you apply reduceRegion on the sample and reference point. That returns a dictionary and from that dictionary you can make a constant image using `toImage`. Then you can return that image and you have you constant image based on that dictionary.

```
//Takes an image collection and returns its time series
var sampleTimeSeries = monthlyNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var temp = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), sample_point, 30);
  return temp.toImage().set('Month', image.get('Month')).set(temp).toFloat();
}); 
print('sampleTimeSeries', sampleTimeSeries);

var referenceTimeSeries = monthlyNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var temp = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), reference_point, 30);
  return temp.toImage().set('Month', image.get('Month')).set(temp).toFloat();
});
print('referenceTimeSeries', referenceTimeSeries);
// plot an constant image on the map
Map.addLayer(referenceTimeSeries.first(), {}, 'first image')
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d49e86997bbffbbe7c07fcc110c2542b)